# MATLAB: writing an anonymous function with sum

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have to test the following problem in an optimization course.
The following function f(c) is used to fit a set of data Dn.
[image]
I wish to minimize this function, using the steepest descent algorithm, shown below:

```
function x=steep_descent_non_quad(f,nablaf,x0,tol,kmax)
% f is a scalar function on R^n
% nablaf is a vector function on R^n
x=x0;r=nablaf(x0);RelErr=1;k=1;n0=norm(x0);
while (k<=kmax)&&(RelErr>tol)
% Compute the optimal step
alpha=optim(f,d,x,tol/2);
% The function optim seeks an approximation to the exact optimal alpha_k
% Using either bisection or golden section
x=x-alpha*r;
RelErr=abs(alpha)*norm(d)/n0;
% Compute new remainder
r=nablaf(x);
k=k+1;
end
```

I want to write the function f(c) in a way that fits its use in the algorithm.
Let's say I write it this way

```
f = @(c) (sum( ( c(1)*x + c(2) + c(3)*exp(-(x - c(4)).^2 ./ c(5)) - y).^2 ));
```

Is this correct?
Will this function provide the sum from i to n?
Or should I write it otherwise?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can’t read your equation. I know latex, but parsing it by eye is way too much effort. You could render it and upload the image.

Comment: `sum` sums the elements of the input vector, or the columns of the input array. So you need to give it the right vector as input. If `x` and `y` are vectors, you might want to use `.*`, `./` and `.^`, the operators without dots do matrix multiplication, matrix division (ie solving system of linear equations) and matrix exponentiation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo fixed it, sorry for that